# Error al enviar formulario email PHP y JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, formularios

Llevo mucho tiempo detrás, y siempre salta la alerta por el error 500.

> "Sorry APA, it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please
> try again later!"

He verificado todas las URL, etc...

No sé si puede ser error de código, o de importaciones de librerias.

Ayuda por favor,

gracias!

**index.html:**

```
<!-- Contact Start -->
<div class="container-fluid py-5" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <h1 class="display-1 text-uppercase text-white" style="-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #dee2e6;">Contact</h1>
            <h1 class="position-absolute text-uppercase text-primary">Contact Me</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="contact-form text-center">
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="control-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control p-4" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"
                                    required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control p-4" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"
                                    required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control p-4" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"
                                required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a subject" />
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control py-3 px-4" rows="5" id="message" placeholder="Message"
                                required="required"
                                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message"></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Send
                                Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Contact End -->
```

**contact.js:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
        },
        submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var subject = $("input#subject").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();

            $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
            $this.prop("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: "mail/contact.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    subject: subject,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append('</div>');
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + name + ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.prop("disabled", false);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        },
        filter: function () {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

$('#name').focus(function () {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**contact.php:**

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  http_response_code(500);
  exit();
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$m_subject = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$to = "name@dominio.com"; // Change this email to your //
$subject = "$m_subject:  $name";
$body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\n\nEmail: $email\n\nSubject: $m_subject\n\nMessage: $message";
$header = "From: $email";
$header .= "Reply-To: $email";  

if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
  http_response_code(500);
?>
```

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta a ver si te sirve [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012718/sorry-it-seems-that-my-mail-server-is-not-responding-please-try-again-la)

Comment: No me ha servido pero gracias!